# The individual parts work, but piping data through them breaks it

Tags: unix, shell, python, sed

In short: I am trying to build another output for ping, that works better for some stuff I am trying to do. For that, I pipe the ping output to sed, to remove everything but the milliseconds it takes. The last part is written in python, and it creates the output.
Here is the code:

```
ping google.com | sed '/^[^=]*$/d;s/^[^=]*=[^=]*=[^=]*=//;s/ ms//' | python3 -c 'while True:
    l = [float(input()) for _ in range(10)]
    m = sum(l) / len(l)
    n = sum(abs(i - m) for i in l) / len(l)
    print("{}\t{}".format(m, n))'
```

I tried to run it in fish and bash, and it doesn't work (=> I get no output). The individual parts work however, `ping google.com | sed '/^[^=]*$/d;s/^[^=]*=[^=]*=[^=]*=//;s/ ms//'` yields the expected output. The python script yields the expected output if I use cat to pipe a file into it.

Comment: @John1024 It outputs the average and the average deviation, with a tab in between. But it doesn't really matter. `cmd1 | cmd2 > f` followed by `cat f | cmd3` should be equivalent to `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`. (With the delay in between the outputs) But in this case it isn't, for some reason I am not aware of.

Comment: @John1024 I get no output. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual when such behavior is observed (no output or delayed output), it is due to pipeline buffering. Your command works here if you instruct `sed` to be "unbuffered" with the `-u` flag.

You can change the buffering behavior of individual programs with the `stdbuf` program from `coreutils`, e.g. to use line buffering:

```
stdbuf -oL sed '...'
```

By the way, if your version of `grep` supports Perl regular expressions, you can achieve the same effect with a lookahead pattern, e.g.:

```
grep --line-buffered -oP '[0-9.]+(?= ms)'
```

Comment: I especially like the `grep` option you provided, but I don't have any Perl regex support. You could still use `grep` though: `grep --line-buffered -oE '[0-9.]+ ms' | grep --line-buffered -oE '[0-9.]+'`, but `sed` is only one call.